# Unable to troubleshoot heroku log message No web processes running

Tags: heroku

I pushed my flask app to Heroku and I'm trying to connect through my frontend for the first time.  I was getting a 503 Error and did a `heroku log` which revealed

> desc="No web processes running".

I double checked my Procfile, deleted it, saw that git was noticing the changes to the file, made sure there was no extension to the file, then recreated it and pushed it back to heroku and ran `heroku ps:scale web=1` but I'm still getting

> Couldn't find that formation.

Is there anything else I should try?

This is what I have inside the Procfile `web: gunicorn manage:app`.  I'm creating the Procfile on TextEdit, could that be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This might be obvious to others, but it took me a while to figure it out.  I was using TextEdit on my Mac to create the Procfile.  I made sure to delete the extension after creating the file.  Apparently, thats not good enough.  I went into google drive and created a Procfile.txt then downloaded it to my apps root directory and removed the extension.  Pushed the changes and ran `heroku ps:scale web=1` and it worked.